# Using authorize in a sentence

Tags: grammar

> He is authorized individual support in the table A, 55 form.

Or

> He is authorized to receive individual support in the table A,55 form.

Which one is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible to use ***authorize*** "transitively" in contexts like *The boss authorized payment [of her invoice]*, but the passive form *She was authorized payment [by the boss]* isn't idiomatically valid. It would need to be rearranged into something like ***Her payment** was authorized by the boss*. Or perhaps *She was authorized **to be paid** [by the boss]*, but not really *She was authorized **payment** by the boss.*

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. Well, the "he is authorised to receive individual support" bit is; without context I can't judge the correctness of the part that says "in the table A,55 form". However, they will be seen in different contexts and people will struggle more with the first than the second.

The second is easy to follow even for someone who isn't familiar with the subject matter, or who is less comfortable with business English. It makes sense, all the verbs are there to help people understand what is being said.

The first version is a form that you will see quite often, especially in business and bureaucratic environments where brevity is favoured over clarity. In the second, the argument of *authorise* is a verb phrase (specifically an infinitive phrase), thus indicating how the "individual support" relates to the person. In the first, the argument (object) of *authorise* is the noun phrase "individual support in the table A, 55 form", which was the object of the infinitive phrase in the second version.

Patterns where someone is authorised a thing, rather than an action, will happen a fair amount, especially in bureaucracy:

> You are authorised a uniform and rations
>   You are authorised to receive a uniform and rations
>
> Students are authorised access to all collections in the library
>   Students are authorised to access all collections in the library

Where there is an "unwritten verb", it is simply expected that the reader will be able to infer it - either from context or from their existing knowledge of the system.

So, which you should use depends on context, but when in doubt use the clearer version, even if it is more wordy.